# strokeRect - Canvas drawing with HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, shapes

Hi I am playing around with shapes and canvas and I have a question:

So say I have this code that draws a nice rectangle on the canvas:

```
$("#create_rectangle").bind("click", function() {   
        if(canvas[0].getContext){
            var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
            ctx.strokeRect(50,50,50,50);
        }
    });
```

Now I say I want to store a reference to that rectangle so that I can make alteration to it at a later stage. The stokeRect() method does not seem to return any value. How do I reference that particular rectangle that was created?

Comment: I wrote an object model for canvas (fabric.js) specifically for this purpose. [Take a look at it](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/demos/kitchensink/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can't reference it, but you can include it in a draw function which depending your arguments allow you to move/rotate hide etc.

It very depend on what you want to do with this shape.

This tutorial can be helpfull to understand manipulation of shape.
http://simonsarris.com/blog/140-canvas-moving-selectable-shapes

Comment: mainly what i want to do is to be able to resize and move the shape.

Comment: Have you check the part 2 of the tutorial I linked ?
http://simonsarris.com/blog/225-canvas-selecting-resizing-shape

It is about resize and select shapes with canvas :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Canvas is basically just a canvas. You throw some paint at it, it dries and you're done. You can't take your paint and move it somewhere else—but you can paint over it.

What you may want is SVG. It keeps track of shapes and other assorted things so that you can change them, deal with interactions much more precisely, et cetera.